# how to check whether a particular attribute name present or not

Tags: jquery, html

am trying to add a class name "selected" to a particular li has attribute name ="3".am also trying this dynamically.

```
<ul>
<li name="1"></li>
<li name="2"></li>
<li name="3"></li>
<li name="5"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `$('li[name="3"]').addClass('selected')` and what do you mean by _dynamically_?

Comment: @Satpal Don't really need quotes here for 3.

Comment: @Suresh Yep, but no harm in using it. Can't help, It has become practice

Comment: @Satpal haha. just to make it cute :D

Comment: trying dynamically check whether  if name="3" present then add class selected like

Answer (score 0):

You can use attribute equals selector here:

```
$('li[name=3]').addClass('selected')
```

Answer (score 0):

On the click handler's callback, this refers to the clicked `<li>.` You may want to add a class just for these list items, or place them in a div with such class, this will allow you to target them and bing the event to them. Also, note that alt is invalid here, you're probably looking for title.

```
    $('li').click(function(){
   var justify = $(this).attr('alt');
   alert(justify);
});
```

You may want to set an hidden field to that value. You can do that, for example, by adding

```
$('#hiddenJustify').val(justify)
```

Since you have five groups of these `<li>`s, you probably want to group them under one element. For example:

```
<div class="line-justify-group">
   <ul>
       <li>...</li>
       <li>...</li>
       <li>...</li>
   </ul>
   <input type="hidden" name="line1justify" id="line1justify" class="justify-value" />
</div>
```

You can then set it using the code:

```
$(this).closest(".line-justify-group").find(".justify-value").val(justify);
```

The items will then be posted to the server.

Answer (score 0):

DOM approach,

```
document.getElementsByName("3").className="selected";
```

JQuery approach,

```
$('li[name="3"]').addClass('selected');
```

CSS approach 
//i have note tried this one but hope so it will work

```
li [name="3"], .Selected {
    background:red;
}
```

:-)